# Is there a C API for python array.array?

Tags: python

Is there a C API for python array.array? I'm trying to create variable-length arrays of floats in a bit of C code and having to convert each double to a python float before letting the array convert it right back again...

Comment: Yes, since they're implemented in C. See [arraymodule.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52256a5861fa/Modules/arraymodule.c).

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Comment: Nope! I guess it can be done if you know the source, but I'm still not sure what this means for development & deployment